# Debugging swig extensions for Python

Tags: python, debugging, swig

Is there any other way to debug swig extensions except for doing

```
gdb python stuff.py
```

?

I have wrapped the legacy library [libkdtree++](http://libkdtree.alioth.debian.org/) and followed all the swig related memory managemant points (borrowed ref vs. own ref, etc.). But still, I am not sure whether my binding is not eating up memory. It would be helpful to be able to just debug step by step each publicized function: starting from Python then going to via the C glue binding into  C space, and returning back.

Is there already such a possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for debugging, you use a debugger ;-).

When debugging, it may be a good idea to configure Python with '--with-pydebug' and recompile.  It does additional checks then.

If you are looking for memory leaks, there is a simple way:

Run your code over and over in a loop, and look for Python's memory consumption.

Comment: What I meant is: is there a debugger that supports that switching of language boundaries? Like, pdb switches to gdb when entering the swig part.

Answer (score 3):

gdb 7.0 supports python scripting. It might help you in this particular case.